# codeigniter fatal error using $this not in object context

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am beating my head against the wall on this. I have a codeigniter application that I am migrating from one server to another. When migrated, I throws an error (it doesn't in production).

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /SYSTEM_PATH/system/database/DB.php on line 146
```

It's a stock CI install 2.1.3 as far as the system folder goes.

I've already tried re-uploading/migrating (hoping it was a corrupt file or something), but no luck.

Comment: are you using the same version of php?

Comment: Yes, both servers are running identical (as far as I can tell) configurations. v5.4.17

Comment: what does DB.php look like? especially line 146 ?

Comment: It's the standard/stock file. " if ($this->db->autoinit == TRUE)" - https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too big for a comment:

(Are you sure you downloaded a stable version - or did you use the development version of CI?)

In 2.1.3 Line 142 to 156 looks like below, no mention of `$this` in there

```
// Instantiate the DB adapter
$driver = 'CI_DB_'.$params['dbdriver'].'_driver';
$DB = new $driver($params);

if ($DB->autoinit == TRUE)
{
    $DB->initialize();
}

if (isset($params['stricton']) && $params['stricton'] == TRUE)
{
    $DB->query('SET SESSION sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"');
}

return $DB;
```

Check here https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1.3/system/database/DB.php

Comment: Not sure how that happened.. but that did it.