# Codeigniter fatal error using $this

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss

Using Codeigniter 2.2.1

I am attempting to parse an RSS feed using this example:
http://hasokeric.github.io/codeigniter-rssparser/

I have downloaded the library and added to my libraries folder.

I then added this code to my view:

```
function get_ars() 
{
    // Load RSS Parser
    $this->load->library('rssparser');

    // Get 6 items from arstechnica
    $rss = $this->rssparser->set_feed_url('http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index/')->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed(6);

    foreach ($rss as $item)
    {
        echo $item['title'];
        echo $item['description'];
    }
}
```

When I call the function `get_ars();` I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp\www\xxxx\application\views\pagetop_view.php on line 8

I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799318/codeigniter-fatal-error-using-this-not-in-object-context), but it didn't solve my issue.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Is this function in a class declaration?

Comment: @Rizier123 No. To be honest, I was expecting the instructions on the site to show it in a controller, but it didn't. Maybe I need to create a controller and access the method that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

and after this use $CI instead of $this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't directly include the function code in the view.
Create a **helper function** and then use it inside your view. For instance,

**1) helpers/xyz_helper.php**

```
function get_ars() 
{
    $ci =& get_instance();

    // Load RSS Parser
    $ci->load->library('rssparser');

    // Get 6 items from arstechnica
    $rss = $ci->rssparser->set_feed_url('http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index/')->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed(6);

    foreach ($rss as $item)
    {
        echo $item['title'];
        echo $item['description'];
    }
}
```

**2) Load the helper in your autoload file (config/autoload.php)**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('xyz_helper');
```

**3) Now you can use it in view**

```
<?php 
$ars = get_ars(); 
foreach($ars as $a) {
?>
...
...
<?php } ?>
```

**Read the docs:**
[Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)
[Creating Libraries](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter is a MVC framework. It implies that uou shouldn't be trying to load stuff or write function inside your views.

However you can call functions inside your view. Those function must be written inside an helper.

See this for more detail : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

**EDIT : See Parag Tyagi's answer for the helper solution**

Also, in your case you should be able to achieve what you need just by passing vars from your controller to your view.

I suppose here that your view is loaded inside your index() and your is named "myview".

**Controller :**

```
public function index()
{
    // Load RSS Parser
    $ci->load->library('rssparser');
    $data["rss"] = $ci->rssparser->set_feed_url('http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index/')->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed(6);

   $this->load->view("myview", $data);
}
```

**View :**

```
<?php
foreach ($rss as $item)
{
    echo $item['title'];
    echo $item['description'];
}
?>
```